# Shiny: How to disable download button when there no data?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm working inside a module which queries some data and then shows it on a DT::datatable, I added a download button so I can download the data with the filters applied.
I already called `useShinyjs()` in the main ui file of the app.

But I want to disable the download button in case there is no data.

I've tried the following.

```
observeEvent(data(), {
if (!nrow(data()) > 0) {
shinyjs::disable("download")
} else {
shinyjs::enable("download")
})
```

However the next error message shows up, and the app crashes as soon as I run it.

```
Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=0]
```

ui Code:

```
module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        title = tagList(
          downloadButton(ns("download"), label = "Download data")
        ),
        width = 12,
        tabPanel(
          title = HTML("Documentation"),
          div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll;font-size:90%', DTOutput(ns("table")))
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

server Code:

```
module_server <- function(id, 
                          connection,
                          update_button,
                          update_button_name) {



 moduleServer(
    id = id,
    module = function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns <- session$ns

  # 1 . Data -----
  
  data <- eventReactive(list(update_button()), {
    data <- dbGetQuery(
      connection, 
      glue::glue("SELECT * FROM Process;)
              
      return(data)
      
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = FALSE)
  
  # 2 . Table -----
  
  output$table<- renderDT({
    
    shiny::validate(
      shiny::need(!is_null(data()) && nrow(data()) > 0, 'No data...')
    )
    
    datatable(
      data = data(),
      selection = "single",
      style = "bootstrap",
      rownames = FALSE,
      filter = 'top',
      options = list(
        searchHighlight = TRUE,
        dom = 'tipr',
        pageLength = 20,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = F, targets = c(0)),
          list(width = "200px", targets = "_all")
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  # 3 . Download -----
  
   observeEvent(data(), {
     if (nrow(data()) > 0) {
       shinyjs::enable("download")
     } else {
       shinyjs::disable("download")
     }
   })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Documentation.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
        
        openxlsx::write.xlsx(
          x = data() %>% slice(input$tabla_rows_all),
          file = file,
          asTable = FALSE,
          row.names = FALSE
        )
        
       
    }
  )
```

Many thanks in advance to whoever can help!

Comment: You are missing a double quote at the of the last download. This will clear your error.

Comment: I made that mistake when writing this post. Im typing it correctly in the app

Comment: Added the ui and server code, hopefully that points to where the problem is.

Comment: Now you are missing a quote here: `glue::glue("SELECT * FROM Process;)`. Please verify that your reproducible example is actually syntactically valid.

Comment: Also there are some opening and closing bracket mismatch. You can further simplify the question by removing unnecessary details from the post. Since we don't have connection to your database `dbGetQuery` command would not work. Change that to `mtcars` or any other default dataset. You can also remove usage of modules since that isn't needed here.

Answer (score -1):

Use `shinyjs::toggleState()` instead. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
  fileInput(
    inputId = "file1", label = "Choose a file to upload:", accept = ".csv"
  ), 
  
  tableOutput(
    outputId = "table1"
  ), 
  
  downloadButton(
    outputId = "download_data", class = "btn-success"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  the_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    the_data() |> head()
  })
  
  # <-- observe if there's any input file -->
  observe({
    # mandatory condition: there should be an input file
    mand_condition <- \() {
      !is.null(input$file1)
    }
    
    shinyjs::toggleState(
      id = "download_data", condition = mand_condition()
    )
  })
  
  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = \() {
      input$file1$name
    }, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(the_data(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```